# How do I fix OCIServerAttach failing with DATABASE error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener?

Tags: oracle

I have my client on a Windows machine and the Oracle server on a Centos Virtual machine.

I am able to connect from my PC to the server using SQLPlus using the following string:

```
sqlplus MyName/MyPassword@IPADDRESS/xe
```

My tnsnames.ora files is:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IPAddress)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

However, when I try to use the same connection information from my application the connections fails in the OCIServerAttach call.

Here is the code framework:

```
OCIEnvCreate(&tmpEnv,
                OCI_OBJECT | OCI_THREADED,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                0,
                NULL);

OCISessionBegin(serviceContextHandle_, errorHandle_, sessionHandle_, OCI_CRED_RDBMS, OCI_DEFAULT);


OCIHandleAlloc( (dvoid *) environmentHandle_, (dvoid **) &serviceContextHandle_, OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);
OCIHandleAlloc( (dvoid *) environmentHandle_, (dvoid **) &serverHandle_, OCI_HTYPE_SERVER, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);
OCIHandleAlloc( (dvoid *) environmentHandle_, (dvoid **) &errorHandle_, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);
OCIHandleAlloc( (dvoid *) environmentHandle_, (dvoid **) &sessionHandle_, OCI_HTYPE_SESSION, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);

 /* here path is an std::string which contains the IPAddress followed by '/xe'*/

result =  OCIServerAttach( serverHandle_, errorHandle_, (text *)path_.c_str(), (sb4)path_.length(), 0);
```

The IPAddress matches the IPAddress in the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora file.  There is no port number being used as I intended to use the default 1521.

To the best of my knowledge the listeners are set up and working correctly otherwise I would not be able to connect via SQLPlus.  My ORACLE_HOME value is as I expect.  The install directory is in my PATH.

Anyone have any ideas of what might be wrong?

Comment: Showing your code might be helpful, along with how you connect from SQL\*Plus - and if that is via a TNS alias, then your `tnsnames.ora` entry for that.

Comment: Good point, I have added more info.  I am extracting the code to make a stand alone piece now.

Comment: I have added the code framework.  Please let me know if there is anything else I can add which would help!

Comment: Added more accurate detail and changed the question title to reflect what is actually happening!

Comment: Is this solved? If so, please move your update to a self-answer post, so it can be accepted.

Comment: @halfer, it is not solved yet.  I just updated it when I found that the error messages from the code were incorrect.

Comment: OK, so what is you real code for `(IPAddress/xe).length` ? If that is too short it may be effectively truncating to a shorter address which is valid but has no listener. Have you debugged all the values actually being sent to the call?

Comment: @AlexPoole, thanks for helping me with this.  The IPAddresses seem to match.  I do not specify the port number as I wanted to use the default.  The port number looks like it is open on the server side.  The real code is just a length call on a std::string.  The string just has an IPAddress followed by '/xe'

Comment: Right.. but you can't pass a `std:string` directly as the third argument, or a `size_t` directly as the fourth (unless I'm missing something...), so there's still something missing from the picture. This seems to come down to the actual values being passed in that call, and we can't help you debug those.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific with what I was saying.  I have updated the example code to show more accurately what is happening.

Comment: That seems to work fine, when I set `path_` to a value I can connect to with SQL\*Plus. From what you've shown I don't see what can be wrong except `path_` not containing the value you think it does, but you seem pretty sure it matches what you used for the SQL\*Plus connection.(Which might not match `tnsnames.ora` I suppose). Aside from double-checking and trying it with the explicit port number, I'm not sure what else to suggest, sorry.

Comment: Based on what you said I went back and copied the IP address and pasted it in SQLPlus's command line.  It turns out I had transposed 2 digits aka you were right - sorry and thanks!!!!! :-)